# Check for exact sentence within a string PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to check if a string contains an exact sentence.

Example:

```
 $sentence = "welcome to";
 $string = "hello and welcome to my website.";
 if(strpos($string, $sentence) !== false) {
    //found PART of "welcome to" in the $string
    //Only want it to come back true is it contains "welcome to".
 }
```

I now want to check if it contains exactelly "welcome to".
Not "come to" or "welcome"... The exact value of $sentence.
Also it needs to be dynamic. So checking from a variable against a variable that could contain any sentence.

Thanks. Martin.

Comment: You can use `strpos()` or `stripos()`

Comment: I have tried strpos, it does not matter if it finds just "we" from "welcome" it will come back true. I need to know it contains "a sentence" from start to finish. So an EXACT match or it simply comes back false.

Comment: *"I have tried strpos"* - So show us then.

Comment: ...and not in comments but in your question.

Comment: Added an example guys :) Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Ok now run it again after removing "to" from $sentence. It will still return as true.

Comment: @Martin Since you say *still return as true* I have the suspicion that you aren't showing us your **real** code! Please show us the code which you use also maybe add a echo statement in the if statement

Comment: @Rizier123 until i get what i have shown working i have nothing more to show in the file. I created the file simply to test if this can be done. If so i will continue to develop the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will be better to get an exact match and using the `\b` word boundary.

```
$string = "hello and welcome to my website.";
if ( preg_match("~\bwelcome to\b~",$string) ){

  echo "Match found.";
  }
else{
  echo "No match found.";
 }
```

---

While doing:

```
~\bcome to\b~
```

won't be a match.

---

**Edit:**

```
// will match
$sentence = "welcome to"; 

// will not match
// $sentence = "come to"; 

$string = "hello and welcome to my website.";

if(preg_match("~\b".$sentence."\b~", $string)){
  echo "An exact match was found.";
  }
else{
  echo "No exact match was found.";
  }
```

---

To add case-insensitivity use the `i` switch:

```
if (preg_match("#\b".$sentence."\b#i",$string))
```

Comment: I found my problem doing it this way.
I need it to work dynamically...
for example: if(preg_match("~\b".$sentence."\b~", $string)){
As the senteces will always be different.

Comment: @Martin That's great Martin, glad to hear you found your final solution, *cheers*

Comment: I wish Fred :( But it does not work dynamically. So i need to find another way sadly! :(

Comment: @Martin Oh, I was under the impression it worked. Ok, so you're wanting to use the `$sentence` variable and see if it contains an exact match?

Comment: @Martin Reload my answer under **Edit:** which worked for me. If you're pulling it from DB, then you will need to show us how it's being pulled in. However, using `$sentence = $_POST['var'];` will work also, if being used with a form etc. You will need to define how the dynamic comes into play.

Comment: Thank you so much fred!!! That done the trick (your edit) I guess the word boundaries helped a lot there. Much appreciated :)

Comment: @Martin You're welcome Martin, glad to have been of help. *Cheers*

Comment: @Martin I've added an additional option for case-insensitivity. Reload near the bottom under *To add case-insensitivity...*. It could come in handy.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sentence = "welcome to";
$string = "Hello and welcome to my website";

if( strstr($sentence, $string)) { 
    // Your code here if $sentence contains $string
} 
else{
    // If no contains
}
```

Comment: This wont work. If i was to remove "to" on the $sentence it would still return true because it would still contain "welcome".

Comment: Because if it finds part of the sentence it will go through ok. I need it to find ALL of the sentence to go through ok... lol